# Function changing a variable, even when passed by value?

Tags: c++

This is what I have, and it's causing some extremely weird discrepancies.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void input_data(int data[], short size);

int main(){
short size;
int data[1000];

cout << "How many values would you like to store? ";
cin >> size;

while (size > 0){
cout << "Enter your " << size << " values:" << endl;
input_data(&data[1000], size);
cout << size << " values stored in array." << endl;
}
}

void input_data(int data[], short size)
{
     int i;
     for (i=0;i<size;i++){
         cin >> data[i];
     }
}
```

So this code should be pretty straight forward, but any time I enter a value other than 3 for `size` ,  the line `cout << size << " values stored in array." << endl;` ends up saying "0 values stored in array."

I don't understand how `input_data` could be changing the value of `size`, since I am passing by value, not by reference.

Why is this happening, and better yet, why is it working with the number 3?

Comment: Think about this: `&data[1000]`.

Comment: `input_data(&data[1000], size);` I don't think this does what you think it does. You should read your book more carefully.

Comment: I'm only passing the array by reference, not `size`, so I don't know what you're getting at

Comment: *"I'm only passing the array by reference"* No you are not. Please, please stop programming based on guessing. C++ is *very* much not the language for that, it's just too weird.

Comment: It's a nice endless loop too since size will never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the stack.

First you declare a function that takes an array:

```
void input_data(int data[], short size);
```

And then you call it.  Instead of passing a pointer to the first element of the array like this:

```
input_data(data, size);
input_data(&data[0], size);
```

You are passing a pointer to the space immediately AFTER the array (which includes many things including size):

```
input_data(&data[1000], size);
```

While a parameter of `data` and `&data[0]` are essentially the same, `&data[1000]` points to a completely different thing - it points to the address of `data[1000]` which doesn't exist in the array because the array only has 1000 elements (from 0 to 999)